# Python, extract tags and also get position of word

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I have a String,

```
data = 'very <strong class="keyword">Awesome</strong> <strong class="keyword">Book</strong> discount'
```

I want to get the output in a list as

```
ans = ['very','<strong class="keyword">Awesome</strong>','<strong class="keyword">Book</strong>','discount']
```

So i can have the position of the word and also the words occurred in  tags.
I used BeautifulSoup to extract words in  and the word with are not in . But i need to find the position.
The code i tried.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
data = 'very <strong class="keyword">Awesome</strong> <strong class="keyword">Book</strong>'
soup = BS(data)
to_extract = soup.findAll('strong')
[comment.extract() for comment in to_extract]
soup = str(soup)
notInStrongWords = []
for t in to_extract:
    t_soup = BS('{0}'.format(t))
    t_tag = t_soup.strong
    matchWords.append(t_tag.string)
soup = re.sub("[^A-Za-z0-9\\-\\.\\(\\)\\\\\/\\&': ]+",' ', soup)
soup = re.findall('[(][^)]*[)]|\S+', soup)
InStrongWords = []
InStrongWords = [x for x in soup]
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The input -> output statement in your question does not appear to discriminate between <strong> and not <strong> - it's a list of all the tags. However the code then does looks for specifically <strong>. Is this needed as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Andrew Alcok's answer, Thank you Ansrew.

lets say,

```
data = ['very <strong class="keyword">Awesome</strong> <strong class="keyword">Book</strong>','<strong class="keyword">Awesome</strong> <strong class="keyword">Book</strong> discount']
```

so for python 2.x and BeautifulSoup 4

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
for d in data:
    soup = BS(d)
    soupPTag = soup.p
    if soupPTag:
        soupList = [unicode(child) for child in soupPTag.children if child!=" "]
        print soupList
    else:
        soupBodyTag = soup.body
        soupList = [unicode(child) for child in soupBodyTag.children if child!=" "]
        print soupList
```

This will give required answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try (for Python 2.x - Python 3 does unicode differently):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
data = 'very <strong class="keyword">Awesome</strong> <strong class="keyword">Book</strong>'
soup = BS(data)
pTag = soup.p
list = [ unicode(child) for child in pTag.children ]
print list
```

Returns:

```
[u'very ', u'<strong class="keyword">Awesome</strong>', u' ', u'<strong class="keyword">Book</strong>']
```

Basically, iterating over the child elements and turn them back into Unicode string. You may want to filter out the space, but this is technically present in your HTML.

If you need to check which children are "strong", you could do something like this:

```
import bs4

data = 'very <strong class="keyword">Awesome</strong> <strong class="keyword">Book</strong>'
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(data)

list = [ (child.name if isinstance(child, bs4.Tag) else None, unicode(child)) for child in soup.children ]
print list
```

Which returns a list of tuples, each tuple being the (name of the tag or *None* where no tag, HTML):

```
[(None, u'very '), (u'strong', u'<strong class="keyword">Awesome</strong>'), (None, u' '), (u'strong', u'<strong class="keyword">Book</strong>')]
```

Comment: Running the same code is not iterating on the the soup variable as <html> and <body> tag are added to it. for the results were like this [u'<html><body><p>very <strong class="keyword">Awesome</strong> <strong class="keyword">Book</strong></p></body></html>'] ... I am using python 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

[`re.finditer`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.finditer) (instead of `re.findall`) gives you [match](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.MatchObject) objects that you can get the `start()` and `end()` of.

Comment: Can you please provide an example.

Comment: This will provide me the position of the 'very' and 'discount' as the words in 'strong' are already extracted using BeautifulSoup. May be I have to try a whole new approach without using BeautifulSoup.